# ejabberd show error while configure at time of installation

Tags: linux, centos, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to configure **eJabberd** on my server.

I have installed all dependencies and other needed things. **ERL**  also installed success fully through RPM with run result

```
root@sXX-XX-XX-XX [~]# erl -smp disable
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.1] [source-2882b0c] [64-bit] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.1  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

For final installation of eJabberd i have followed below link :

http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/

I have tried `make clean` also for it and after try `./configure --enable-mysql`  than also i am facing continue below error.

```
root@sXX-XX-XX-XX [/etc/ejabberd_downloads/ejabberd]# ./configure
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for erl... /usr/bin/erl
checking for erlc... /usr/bin/erlc
checking for erl... /usr/bin/erl
checking for erlc... /usr/bin/erlc
checking Erlang/OTP version... 
Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...
Failed to create aux thread
./configure: line 2523:  1636 Aborted                 $ERLC conftest.erl
configure: error: "Could not compile Erlang/OTP version check program using '/usr/bin/erlc'"
```

For **erl_crash.dump** few lines as below from top

```
=erl_crash_dump:0.3
Thu Nov 19 01:31:57 2015
Slogan: Failed to create aux thread
System version: Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.1] [source-2882b0c] [64-bit] [smp:64:24] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Compiled: Wed Sep 23 15:34:00 2015
Taints:
Atoms: 2005
Calling Thread: beam.smp
=scheduler:1
Scheduler Sleep Info Flags: SLEEPING | TSE_SLEEPING
Scheduler Sleep Info Aux Work: SET_TMO
Current Port:
Run Queue Max Length: 0
Run Queue High Length: 0
Run Queue Normal Length: 1
Run Queue Low Length: 0
Run Queue Port Length: 0
Run Queue Flags: NONEMPTY_NORMAL | NONEMPTY
Current Process:
=scheduler:2
```

`which erl` result as below :

```
/usr/bin/erl
```

I am not able to trace the issue, Any reference will be very helpful. Thanks in advence.

Comment: What does the `ulimit` command tell you? Do you have a very low number of user processes allowed?

Comment: Maybe you have security limits on your server or right issue that prevent Erlang compiler to work. You should try compiliing a basic Erlang module to see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Erlang version is corrupted or Old, Reinstall it and try again. For Ejabberd 16.x version 6.1 (Erlang/OTP 17.1) is required.
You can uninstall Erlang with following command:

$ sudo apt-get purge erlang*

And install latest Erlang from http://www.erlang.org/